# Responsive Design/Viewports

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, viewport, font-size

Let's say I have a website that looks like this in its mobile view:
[image: As you can see, the font is way too small]

What would be the best way to make the font more readable?

The viewport is currently configured as follows:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=1366, user-scalable=yes">
```

Would changing that to

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

make any difference? Are there any online emulators that can show me how the site would look with that viewport? I'm new to this obviously, but so far I've been using mobilephoneemulator.com, where I can see my changes to the CSS, but not changes to the viewport.

I have also tried increasing the fonts, but it seems like the font size has to be increased to a large value in order for the text to be readable, so that's why I thought the issue might be with the viewport or something other than the size of the font.

Answer (score 2):

The reason the text is so small, is you are telling the browser that the width of the phone is 1366px basically zooming out from the website.
So yes, using:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

Should fix the problem.